# Accessing a remote Windows "Git Bash" prompt from a Linux machine?

Tags: windows, linux, bash, git, msysgit

"Git Bash" is a program that comes with [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.com/). In order to get to a Git Bash prompt on a remote Windows machine from a linux machine, my usual process is to use [remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) to open an RDP connection, then to open a new Git Bash window.

Is there a way to log in using my bash shell instead of having to muck with GUI stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) lets you use SSH to log in to the Windows box remotely to access the command line shell...

**EDIT** I found this [PowerShell server](http://www.powershellinside.com/powershell/ssh/) (free for personal usage with 1 connection)

Comment: The original question is specific in asking about using the msysgit bash shell...

Comment: @Thell: What keeps one from starting the git bash shell from Powershell? BTW your solution does exactly the same: log in through SSH of some kind, then start the git bash shell. But not the second step was the tough one, IMHO.

Comment: Good point.  Nothing at all.

Comment: More recent information about PowerShell Remoting over SSH [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core)

Answer (score 6):

All you need is an ssh server that allows you to define your startup.

For example, [freesshd](http://www.freesshd.com/), then set the command shell to the same as your normal git bash shortcut would set it, ( `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"` ).  Since freesshd can run as a service you'll always be good to go.