# How could I access my windows PC's Git Bash from Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, git, synergy, git-bash

I am trying to achieve something a bit odd. I currently have a dual monitor setup , with my laptop beside, linked with synergy. I want to connect to my windows PC from my Linux mint laptop and Control my Git Bash Windows. (Essentially I want to use my laptop as a third monitor but only for git bash windows). I thought i could SSH into my windows computer from the terminal in linux but that only gives me access to powershell and cmd. I want to be able to launch the git bash command line. how could I go about doing this? I tried searching for answers, I found one that is similar to my question but it didn't work the way i wanted it to, or it does and I do not understand how to implement it. that is linked Here:

[Accessing a remote Windows "Git Bash" prompt from a Linux machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/492898/accessing-a-remote-windows-git-bash-prompt-from-a-linux-machine)

I do apologize if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps or not - but instead of trying to run git on the windows command line (in a git-bash shell), would it be an acceptable alternative to mount the windows folder onto your linux machine as an external drive and use git installed on the laptop?